# Mounted disk suddenly became readonly

Tags: 12.10, hardware, disk

While running Ubuntu, sometimes my disks suddenly become read-only, and any write attempt on it result in error: `Read-only file system`, but mount -l shows that disk as `rw`.

After restarting, some failures are detected in disk and `fsck` fix the problem, but after a while all of this happens again. What is the cause of this situation and how it can be fixed permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the system logs for HDD related errors. Use `smartctl -a` output to check for reallocated sectors count. Most probably your HDD is about to fail badly.

Comment: Well, not a very a comprehensive answer, but accepted for noting the probability of HDD failure. In fact, my HDD became completely unusable after a few day and even ubuntu was unable to boot.